# Android Studio 2.3.2 Unable to build project due to error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android studio gradle build error occurred after gradle build crashed a few times:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'.

Unknown constant tag 111 in class file org/antlr/v4/runtime/CommonTokenFactory

Environment:

Mac OSX Yosemite

Android Studio 2.3.2

JAVA 6 (downgraded due to constant AS crashes and failed to startup AS)

Gradle-3.3 (gradle/wrapper/gradle-3.3)

com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2

buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

I've tried reinstalling AS and also recovering my java and xml layout files to a previous working version but with no luck.

Anyone has experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clean and build project again after downloading gradle wrapper 3.5 from https://gradle.org/releases and placing the extracted files in gradle/wrapper, update the gradle wrapper in AS Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > select use Local gradle distribution > set Gradle home: /path_to/gradle/wrapper/gradle-3.5 > Apply and restart AS > clean and build project.